# Many files jvm.pid.bkp created under tomcat directory

Tags: jvm, cpanel, pid

I am having a very weird problem on my Java hosting. It seems to be reverting changes I have made. I have deleted all cache and all ROOT.war files. Exported a new ROOT.war file and uploaded it to the server and started the JVM. I usually do this late at night so no users are active.

Test and all seems to be perfect. Then the following day my users start using the system and run into all the problems I had the previous day before making the changes.

I see hundreds of these files created under the tomcat directory:

`jvm.pid.bkp_2019-05-21-071002`

Such a file is generated every 10 minutes. It seems like a backup or restore is done and my changes are replaced with old code. I have no idea what the cause could be. Any of you have any idea?

Comment: Do you stop tomcat before redeploying the application?

Comment: Yes, stop, delete all files, deploy WAR file and then start. This is however on a hosted server, so I am not sure if the hosting company set something on their side.

Comment: What's in those `jvm.pid...` files?

Comment: Just a number such as 9612. No idea what it means. For now just deleting the files every few days.

Comment: That sounds like a PID - maybe just the pid of your tomcat process?
I'd check if the current state of the deployed war/class files contain expected code changes to make sure they aren't replaced by something.
Definitely it sounds weird...

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.